# Entity Framework Core failed for a complex existing database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

I am working on a mvc web application with a sql server 2012 database about 200 tables. Entity Framework 5, 6 is working fine. Entity Framework Core scaffolded models and DbContext without error. however, when using the context in a controller, i.e. retrieving data from a simple table, will cause the application exit without any error or exception. Further more, running visual studio 2017 controller code generator will cause stack overflow exception. The exact same steps applied to a simple database with Entity Framework Core 2.0 works fine. So I can rule out the error of using the tool. Any advise is appreciated to identify the problem.

Comment: Core is young, and not all that is possible in EF 6 is supported. Without details about your schemas or some errormessage its kindof hard to crystalball the error :/ - maybe ask the Core.EF Team and provide details?

Comment: Use EF Core 2.  Why in the world are you using 4 different versions for your code?  EF 5, 6, Core 1 and Core 2?  Generally that is the exact opposite of best practice.

Comment: I did not use at the same time. I meant I tried all of them separately.